# Python - Click to scroll to bottom using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium in Python to extract a list of startups from AngelList. In order to collect all startups, I have to click the button 'More' at the end of the page until I reach the end of the list.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to keep clicking until it reaches the end of the page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("""more""").click()
```

This results in one click of "More". Each click loads 20 more startups.

I have tried this in order to keep clicking:

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("""more""").click()
    i += 1
```

and it results in this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale 
element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when it reaches the end of the page, the element `<div class="more">More</div>` will be removed from the DOM.

To click and load more content, wait and check if the button or `div.more` has text `More`, here the example using `WebDriverWait` and filtered results URL

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get('https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup&markets[]=Education&raised[min]=2830196&raised[max]=100000000&stage[]=Series+B&stage[]=Series+A')

while True:
    try:
        moreButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="more" and text() = "More"]')
        )
        moreButton.click()
    except:
        print("scroll finished")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did work better than my other tries, I'm just not sure it captured all 2000~ companies I was looking for, but thank you!